# How to run flask CLI command in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have my flask server running in AWS Elastic Beanstalk, however, I want to run some custom flask CLI commands that are listed in **commands.py** file of my repository. Previously when my server was hosted in Heroku, I was able to run these commands through the Heroku console, however I'm unable to figure out how to run these commands in Elastic Beanstalk or even go inside of the beanstalk environment and run my custom flask commands through the command line.

I tried using the *eb cli* but that seems to only allow me to mainly deploy, terminate, open the Elastic Beanstalk environment but nothing in the *eb cli* seems to allow me to even run `flask --help` inside the environment

Answer (score 0):

> even go inside of the beanstalk environment

If you use eb cli, then it would be `eb ssh` to ssh into your instance.

> I'm unable to figure out how to run these commands in Elastic Beanstalk

Generally you would create [.ebextentions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) config files with [commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) or [container_commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) to run the actual flask commands.

There are also other options, such as [platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

Comment: So i did "eb ssh" into my instance, but even doing "flask --help" gives the error that the command is not found - any way to fix this?

Comment: @ManasChakka You have to activate python virt env of your app. it will be `/var/app/...` don't remember fully now. Just check in `/var/app` and activate it.